# Matlab shortcuts not working

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, matlab

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity and I can't seem to be able to use any shortcuts on Matlab. It appears that they go directly to Unity and bypass Matlab all together.

For instance, if I press <kbd>F10</kbd> to do Debug->Step, it opens up dropdown menu under the icon 'mail'.

How can I can I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you use a matlab shortcut that does not exist in Unity? If this works you could work around the issue by redefining your shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really catch your question. You want to create a desktop shortcut or shortcut on the side bar. If you want to create the desktop shortcut, the following tutorial is quite easy to follow

> http://www.linuxandlife.com/2012/07/how-to-create-launcher-in-linux-mint-13.html

Just install gnome-desktop-item-edit and use it. After create the .desktop file, you also need to download icon for the shortcut. Just google it.

This is my code of .desktop file

```
 #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=/
Name[en_US]=MATLAB-R2012a
Exec=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/matlab -desktop
Comment[en_US]=Running MATLAB
Name=MATLAB-R2012a
Comment=Running MATLAB
Icon=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/matlabicon.png
```

Regards,

Nam